# Getting my first jsFiddle code to work - using a jquery AutoComplete with Grep

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jsfiddle

I am trying to create a new jsFiddle so that I can ask a question here on StackOverflow, and I can't get the basic code that is working in my Aspnet app to work in jsFiddle. To see the example that does not work in jsFiddle:

[jquery AutoComplete](http://jsfiddle.net/EqsmV)

What am I doing incorrectly?

(At the end of the day, what I really wnat to know is how to clear an html input texbox after the function AutoCompleteSelectionHandler2 runs in my app. I have tried

```
 $('#Text2').val("");
```

,as I have seen in StackOverflow, in the js function but it does not work.

If anyone can answer both questions, I will be very happy at you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EqsmV/3/   include jquery UI

Comment: Thank you! Put that in as the answer so I can select it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete is part of `jquery UI`, you have to include it on left part of jsfiddle site:

http://jsfiddle.net/EqsmV/3/

Answer (score 1):

I made an update that gets you closer:

http://jsfiddle.net/EqsmV/5/

You were not including jqueryUI (which is needed for autocomplete).

I also changed your code that says:

```
var selectedId = $get('tbLoc');
var selectedLoc = $get('tbSelected');
```

to

```
var selectedId = $('input[name=tbLoc]').val();
var selectedLoc = $('input[name=tbSelected]').val();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the more cumbersome code to use when debugging and hadn't taken it out.

Comment: Now that I am past that hurdle, any idea why the function AutoCompleteSelectionHandler2 is not getting called?

Comment: It is for me? Open up your console and see if you see any errors being written.

Comment: I put an alert('hello') in the handler and this fiddle has it pop up for me. http://jsfiddle.net/EqsmV/6/

Comment: No upvote for my answer after all that work? I mean, you didn't have to choose this as the right answer--but an upvote would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Thank you. I put in lots of upvotes for you. The one that got the chosen answer vote answered the question first. In any case, am still trying to get what I want to work.